# ValidationException : "The provided key element does not match the schema" Error when doing dynmoDB batchWriteItem operation

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am doing batchWriteItem operation on multiple tables of DynamoDb. My code is as follows -

```
    BatchWriteItemOutcome outcome = null;
    try {
        TableWriteItems userTableWriteItems = new TableWriteItems("User")
                .withHashAndRangeKeysToDelete("clientAccountKey", "userKey", clientAccountKey, "xyzUserKey"); // Working for this Method

        TableWriteItems PosTrackingWriteItems = new TableWriteItems("PosTracking")
                .withHashOnlyKeysToDelete("userKey", "xyzUserKey"); // ** Not Working for this **

        outcome = dynamoDb.batchWriteItem (
                userTableWriteItems,
                PosTrackingWriteItems);     
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Exception in Removing User Data !!! ");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

If I just specify batchWrite delete `withHashAndRangeKeysToDelete` method where I specify Hash and Range key both, it is working. 
But its not working for `withHashOnlyKeysToDelete` method where I specify HashKey name and HashKey Value as paramerters. I keep getting this exception:

> com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.AmazonDynamoDBException: The provided key element does not match the schema. Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException.

My PosTracking table has HashKey (String) as userKey and I am passing String from the method as well. I have a GSI also in this table with name clientAccountKey (String). I tried using `addHashOnlyPrimaryKeysToDelete` & `.addPrimaryKeyToDelete` methods also for TableWriteItems but its not working either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is the primary key schema for the PosTracking table? Does it have a range key? If so you need to specify both the hash key and range key. DynamoDB does not allow you to delete items using just a hash key - you must specify the complete primary key including the range key.

Comment: Then what is the use of this method `withHashOnlyKeysToDelete` Or how can I use this. I checked the documentation and it says to only pass hashKey name and Hash key value Objects.  Even I tried it with mapper. Its able to delete items successfully with just Hash Key.

Comment: `HashMap<String, AttributeValue> eav = new HashMap<String, AttributeValue>();
      eav.put(":v1", new AttributeValue().withS(userKey));
      DynamoDBQueryExpression<PosTracking> queryExpression = new DynamoDBQueryExpression<PosTracking>()
                  .withKeyConditionExpression("userKey = :v1")
                  .withExpressionAttributeValues(eav);
      List<PosTracking> ddbResults = mapper.query(PosTracking.class, queryExpression);
      mapper.batchDelete(ddbResults);`

Comment: The Javadoc for withHashOnlyKeysToDelete says "Used to specify multiple hash-only primary keys to be deleted from the current table." So it used to delete items from a table where the primary key only contains a hash key. The code sample you posted works cause you are first doing a query for all items with the same hash key (which is allowed) then passing all those items to a batchDelete. The items would contain both the hash and range key values, so the delete works

Comment: @bwinant-  really thank you for your reply, I got your point. Do you know any better way to delete 1000s of rows in batch from multiple tables? your help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately there really isn't a nice easy way. A batch operation can have a max of 25 delete requests, so if you need to delete 1000s of items, you would still need to chop that up into multiple batches.  And you need to query or know all the keys beforehand

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot.